# why multoprocessing is decreasing the speed of the code?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am working on a code which is very time-consuming. I am trying to apply multiprocessing to increase speed but the run-time of the code with multiprocessing is more than the original code.
The original code is:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random

class func:

    def __init__(self, i1, i2, i3):
        self.i1 = i1
        self.i2 = i2
        self.i3 = i3

        p = 0.5
        mean = 0
        stddev = 1
        self.N = self.i1 + self.i2 + self.i3
        self.L1 = self.i1 + self.i2

        self.w = np.zeros((self.N,self.N))

        for i in range(0,self.i1):
            for j in range(self.i1,self.L1):
                if random.random() <= p:
                    self.w[i][j] = random.normalvariate(mean, stddev)
        print(self.w)

i_1 = 2
i_2 = 3
i_3 = 2
t1 = time.perf_counter()
n = func(i_1,i_2,i_3)
t2 = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')
```

and the original code with multiprocessing is :

```
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np
import time
import random

class func:

    def __init__(self, i1, i2, i3):
        self.i1 = i1
        self.i2 = i2
        self.i3 = i3

        p = 0.5
        mean = 0
        stddev = 1
        self.N = self.i1 + self.i2 + self.i3
        self.L1 = self.i1 + self.i2

        self.w = np.zeros((self.N,self.N))

        ii = range(self.i1)
        def i_to_h1(i):
            for j in range(self.i1,self.L1):
                 if random.random() <= p:
                     self.w[i][j] = random.normalvariate(mean, stddev)

         with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as 
 executor:
             executor.map(i_to_h1, ii)
         print(self.w)

 i_1 = 2
 i_2 = 3
 i_3 = 2
 t1 = time.perf_counter()
 n = func(i_1,i_2,i_3)
 t2 = time.perf_counter()
 print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')
```

Without multiprocessing it takes 0.0005 seconds to run the code and with multiprocessing it takes 0.0029 second. I don't know why and what to do to increase the speed of the code. I will appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Passing data between processes is expensive. Multiprocessing only makes things that parallelize well faster; part of that is that they can't require moving data around much.

Comment: Well for starters, you aren't using multiprocessing, you are using a ThreadPool... which in CPython, due to the GIL, will only ever run one thread at a time and will only increase performance in I/O bound situations

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well, in this case numpy can't use any of it's internal optimizations because the OP is not taking advantage of any of the vectorized operations of numpy

Comment: Although, for other reasons stated, I highly doubt multiprocessing would be faster either

Comment: well. Thank you. Is there anything I can do to increase speed in my situation?

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga what if I use ProcessPoolExecutor? I tried to do that but It takes a long time to run and finally I had to stop it because nothing happened. I think there is a problem with that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there any other way to increase speed in my situation?